# HandshakeException: Handshake error in client - Flutter http.dart post request?

Tags: ssl, flutter, dart, openssl, boringssl

> HandshakeException (HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:      CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate(handshake.cc:352))) in flutter post request using
>   http.dart package. How can I solve this?

Comment: Given that the question does not provide much details by its own (specifically no code etc) I've marked it as duplicate of a question which looked similar but provided more details. If you feel that this is not a duplicate then please provide enough details to show that your problem is a different one.